# webdav share through gvfs fails upon access

Tags: mount, gvfs, webdav

This is the weirdest thing,
I have a webdav share mounted via gvfs (Gigolo application) on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. I can access all directories fine, except for one - if I try to open that in file manager, the connection to the share is closed, (or it's unmounted - the output of mount -l looks exactly same though before and after), it's not available anymore.
e.g. If I want to list the folder's content, this happens:

```
~$ ls /home/ben/Owncloud/Music
ls: reading directory /home/ben/Owncloud/Music: Input/output error
```

Maybe I should mention that this server is also where the webdav share is coming from.
But again, anything else works ok, just trying to access the one directory shuts everyhting down...